# Decoding and Encoding issue. Different implementations of Base64 Class in android.util.* and java.util.*?

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64, decoding

I am writing an App which does the following with a given String str:

```
encode(encrypt(encode(stringToBytearray(str))));
```

The Server receives the Base64 encoded String, which is then decoded -> decrypted -> decoded, to get the sent String str from the App.

Unfortunately it doesnt work for all Strings, long Strings lead to a long Base64 String and my Server throws the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5b
 at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
 at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
 at Main.decode(Main.java:113)
 at Main.main(ain.java:33)
```

The String has the format "[string, string, ..., string]" without "s.

Like I mentioned above, for Strings which are not too long (sorry I cant quantify the length yet), this works. So I think I implemented it right.

Whats weird is, that if I dont send it, but decode(decrypt(decode(stringToBytearray(str)))); the String on the Device itself, it all works perfectly.

My Setup:
JDK 7, eclipse (adt-bundle, android development) (Windows 7)

JDK 8, eclipse ('normal' java) (Linux (xubuntu))

Is it because both Classes (Base64) are implemented diffrently? If so, how can I make it work?

Here are the Encoding/Decoding Methods:

Encoding (Device: on Windows 7, adt-bundle, Android-Dev, jdk 7):

```
import android.util.Base64

public byte[] encode(byte[] bytearrayToEncode){
   return Base64.encode(bytearrayToEncode, Base64.NO_WRAP|Base64.URL_SAFE);
}
```

Decoding (Server: on Linux, jdk 8):

```
import java.util.Base64

public byte[] decode(byte[] bytearrayToEncode){
   return Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(bytearrayToDecode);
}
```

Strings are all De-/Encoded with the same charset (utf-8)!
Encoding/Decoding: Base64

Crypto: AES

If you need more Information, just ask, but I think I provided all neccessary informations.

Edit:

```
public String bytearrayToString(byte[] bytearray){
    String str = null;
    try {
        str = new String(bytearray, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}

public byte[] stringToBytearray(String str){
    byte[] bytearray = null;
    try {
        bytearray = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bytearray;
}
```

Comment: 0x5b is [, and as I said the String format is [string, ..., string]. But why does all encoding/decoding work on the Device, but not on the Server, when the String is too long. (i compared both long strings, and they are equal)

Comment: Is your server trimming the query param when length is too large? Just try to  echo the received base-64 message and check if they are exactly equal. Because truncated string may no longer be a valid Base-64 encrypted message.

Comment: I just found out, that the second call of encode, does not apply (even though i thought i have checked it). So far, thanks for all suggestions! I will try to figure out why it doesnt.

Comment: I have struggled a bit with the different encoders in java.util.Base64. Have you tried Base64.getDecoder() instead of Base64.getUrlDecoder()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must be using JSONObjects to send the Base64 String to the server. If so then the JSONObject will  add " \ "  escape characters to the string which are illegal Base64 characters. All you need to do is

```
String rectifiedString = Base64String.replace("\\","");
```

on the server end before using the acquired string.

**Optional**

Also on the server side use

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
```

and

`String result = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytearrayToDecode);`

```
byte[] result = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str);
```

instead.

It will not only get the job done but is much faster at encoding/decoding ([as benchmarked here](http://java-performance.info/base64-encoding-and-decoding-performance/)).

Comment: Looks to me like printBase64Binary strips the backslash for you. Thanks for the insight. I had the same issue as OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a space in your encoded string, which is an illegal character in base64. If you remove it, it still generates the same image/data in the converter you linked to, and can be now decoded by your code as well.

**UPDATE:**
Some decoders (like the one you linked, or Base64.getMimeDecoder() in Java) ignore illegal characters, others (like Base64.getDecoder()) don't allow them.

Answer (score 0):

Use for encode:

```java
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(yourString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

and decode:

```java
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(yourString);
String stringDecode = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
```